# char * hex address to ULONG64

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to convert hex address to ulong64 as shown below but none of them are working. Is there any correct way of converting this?

```
std::string s = "0x0000029078cc0000";
ULONG64 startAdress = _strtoul_l(s.c_str(), nullptr, 16, 0);
// output is 0x00000000ffffffff
_atoi64(address);
// output is 0x0000000000000000
sscanf(s.c_str(), "%16x", &startAdress);
// output is 0x000000009078cc00
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] please?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I think you are trying to fix the wrong problem

Comment: Assuming you use [this `_strtoul_l` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k9xb7x1.aspx), it converts to an `unsigned long` which using VC++ is 32 bits even on 64-bit systems. I recommend using [`std::stoull`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stoul) instead.

Comment: Also, what is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Why do you want to convert a string to an "address"? [Related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, working on windows driver and I have a situation to get offset address from virtual address, which is in string.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried std::stoull but this number is too big for it.

Comment: @RedFox Then the number is too big to be handled at your system. You need another idea how to deal with it.

Comment: sscanf(s.c_str(), "%16x", &startAdress); works if I remove leading zeros. "0x0000029078cc0000" to "0x29078cc0000"

Comment: strtoull from stdlib.h will do the job

Comment: @willll this number is too big for strtoull

Comment: You need to pass the actual address of the end of the string not nullptr at least if I am reading this correctly https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab.aspx

Comment: @RedFox : i did tested it successfully, give it a try !

Comment: @willll I get the following error for stoul(s, nullptr, 16);

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFAFB861E68 in pd.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x00000095C3CFFAD0.

Comment: @RedFox, That's a similar but different function, and you're not passing it the args it wants.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoull/

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use?

Comment: `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits, and `0x0000029078cc0000` does not exceed that

Comment: What, are you saying that a 64-bit number is to big for the 64-bit functions to handle? Compared to the functions you seem to be using now which can be 32 bits (or *less* in case of your `scanf` format).

Comment: And you *still* haven't told us what the actual problem you try to solve is.

Comment: Lastly, what do you mean that `std::stoull` doesn't work? Do you have an old VC++ version that doesn't support it? Because [it works fine for me](http://ideone.com/70F9aZ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_atoi64` expects decimal format only, not hexadecimal.

`strtoll` is not available in some earlier versions of Visual Studio

`sscanf` should work fine using `"%llx"` or `"%I64x"` [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx)

You may want to set the compiler warning level to 4, the compiler may actually suggest the correct format specifier.

The following example works in VS2015:

```
ULONG64 startAdress;
std::string s = "0x0000029078cc0000";
std::cout << s << "\n";

startAdress = strtoll(s.c_str(), 0, 16);
printf("%I64x\n", startAdress);

if (sscanf_s(s.c_str(), "%llx", &startAdress) == 1)
    printf("%llx\n", startAdress);

if (sscanf_s(s.c_str(), "%I64x", &startAdress) == 1)
    printf("%I64x\n", startAdress);

std::cout << std::hex;
std::cout << startAdress << "\n";
```